# How to rig/ animate wrinkles/skin stretching?

Tags: animation, rigging

How would I go about rigging/animate complex wrinkles/skin? For example, just look at the skin on your finger joints. When you bend your fingers, the skin on your finger joints are smooth, and when you point your finger straight, the skin on your finger  is wrinkly

Comment: In 2.79 it was possible with Stress Map https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/zQfbbc/  ... I'm not sure about 2.9x

Comment: Tension Map addon for 2.8+ https://blenderartists.org/t/revised-mesh-tension-add-on/1239091/1

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QfbXeP8LgEg

Comment: Thanks, that worked.